# Using acts_as_taggable_on on Rails3 Active Record queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

If I want to select a group of records from a database using a SQL query and further 
qualify it by what tag(s) are set on a record - is there an easy way to do this?

e.g. something conceptually like `Select * from Corps where date_added > '2010-01-01' and tag like "legal"`

Obviously this isn't correct since the tag data isn't kept in the table, but you get the idea.

Rails3 has a new syntax for Active Record queries. Can I select a group of records using the AREL AR syntax, then apply the tag find operation to that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with the `tagged_with()` method.

Example using your sample SQL query:

```
@corps = Corp.where('date_added > 2010-01-01').tagged_with('legal')
```

You can also put an array of tags into tagged_with (`tagged_with(['legal', 'foo'])`).

Comment: what if it was a conditional ? like date_added OR tagged_with ?